# Is precomputation of the prime-factor-decomposition feasible?

Tags: computational-complexity, prime-factorization

It is well-known that the prime-factor-decompositions (PFDs) of the positive integers are useful in a range of mathematical problems.  There are a number of algorithms to compute these decompositions for a specific integer.  Since this query is so ubiquitous in mathematics and computing, I have always wondered whether it would be feasible to [precompute a large repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomputation) of the prime-factor-decompositions for all integers $n = 1,...,N$ up to some large number $N$, to allow the prime-factor-decompositions to be obtained via a simple "lookup" query, rather than being computed during run-time.

In theory, such a thing could be done by some large company/institution, which could then allow public queries of its repository.  That is, you send through a list of integers no greater than $N$ and they send back the PFDs for those integers, in some appropriate syntax.  In computing terms, the runtime computation of the PFD would be replaced by a lookup query to an external repository.  The time taken would consist of sending the query, processing and lookup by the PFD repository, and receiving the answer.  If this time is smaller than the time needed to compute the PFD by an efficient algorithm, then there would be a speed advantage.  I'm just not sure whether this is something that would actually be feasible in practice.

---

**Questions:** Assuming this were done by some large company/research institution (i.e., with plenty of money and storage space), would it be feasible to precompute the prime-factor-decomposition for all integers up to some reasonably large number $N$, such that lookup queries to this institution would be faster than runtime computation?  Roughly speaking, how big would $N$ need to be to get a computing advantage, and how big a value of $N$ would be feasible?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is storage space. The total amount of harddrives ever produced by humanity can store around $10^{21}$ numbers.* But twenty-one-digit numbers are easy to factorise. So we could never store enough factorisations to make this plan worthwhile.

*For citation see here: https://www.zdnet.com/article/what-is-the-worlds-data-storage-capacity/ That's an old article, but it doesn't really matter. Thirty-digit numbers are also easy to factorise.

Comment: This is very helpful information (+1).  Just for reference for others, the relevant paper here referenced by the link you cite is [Hilbert and Lopez (2011)](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/332/6025/60.abstract), and their calculation was up to the end of 2007.  (Presumably the storage capacity would be substantially larger now, though your point remains valid.)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Even $40$ or $50$ digit numbers can be factored in at most a few seconds, and $10^{40}$ is surely beyond the available space no matter of the development of the techniques. $10^{21}$ already sounds very high, but I do not want to doubt the estimation. And even if we had such a huge database, searching an entry will take much more time than a simple calculation.

Comment: A database for factorizations has actually been established, look at factordb. You cannot only look up existing factorizations, you can also enter new numbers. If they are small enough, the program can automatically factor or at least partially factor it. Currently, about $1.45 \cdot 10^9$ numbers are stored in this database.

Comment: about the best we could do, is a pointer to a previous number with one prime less and the required new prime.